# What is the difference between quote and double quote in mssql

Tags: sql-server, quotes

Is there a difference in these two expressions for example?

```
Select [column] as 'column1' from [table]
```

```
Select [column] as "column1" from [table]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Single quotes are for literal strings. Double quotes are the ANSI SQL Delimit Identifier for object names (T-SQL's delimit identifier is brackets (`[]`)).

Don't use single quotes (`'`) for aliases though, as (as mentioned) single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. Single quotes only work as delimit identifiers on aliases when you define said alias, no where else. This means that you can easily confuse those new to the language (and even those who've been using it for years if your formatting is poor).

As an example, `ORDER BY 'column1'` would *not* order by your column aliased as `'column1'`, it would order by the `varchar` literal `'column1'`; effectively your data would not be ordered at all and would be returned in an arbitrary order (as every row has the same value for it ordering). Like wise in the following the 1st statement would return no rows and the second would error:

```sql
SELECT 'Column1'
FROM (SELECT [Column] + '_suffix' AS Column1
      FROM dbo.MyTable) MT
WHERE 'Column1' LIKE 'ID%';
GO
SELECT 'Column1' + 2
FROM (SELECT [SomeIntColumn] AS 'Column1'
      FROM dbo.MyTable) MT;
```

The first would return no rows as the literal `varchar` value `'Column1'` will **never** be `LIKE 'ID%'`. The second would error as although the column has been aliased as `'Column1'`, and it's name suggests it's an `int` column, the outer `SELECT` would try to convert the literal `varchar` value `'Column1'` to an `int`, and (obviously) that won't work.

Also some syntaxes with literal string aliases are deprecated (specifically `'string_alias' = expression`).

Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you *must* delimit identify them use the T-SQL identifier, brackets (`[]`), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (`"`). `column1` does not need identifying, so you should just define is as `column1`.